# SQL Server connections

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query 1 results in 87 rows:

```
SELECT        
    MIN(LEFT(Date_Last_Updated, 4)) AS Year_of_Transfer,  
    MIN(RIGHT(LEFT(Date_Last_Updated, 6), 2)) AS Month_of_Transfer, 
    MIN(RIGHT(LEFT(Date_Last_Updated, 8), 2)) AS Day_of_Transfer, 
    CRS, Loan_Code, 
    MIN(Date_Last_Updated) AS Min_Date_Last_Updated
FROM            
    dbo.Transfer_Final_Accounts_CO_SH
WHERE        
    (LEFT(Date_Last_Updated, 4) >= '2016') 
    AND (Subcategory = 'Transfer to Workout')
GROUP BY 
    CRS, Loan_Code
ORDER BY 
    Loan_Code
```

Query 2 results in 3400000 rows:

```
SELECT        
    Date_Last_Updated, 
    SUM(NPL_Amount_Last_Quarter) AS NPL_Amount_Last_Quarter, 
    Loan_Code, 
    SUM([Total_Balance_€]) AS Total_Balance, 
    SUM(On_Balance_Amount_Last_Quarter) AS On_Balance_Last_Q, 
    SUM([Off_Balance_Amount_€]) AS Off_Balance_Last_Q, CRS, 
    [On_Balance_Amount_€], [Off_Balance_Amount_€], [Total_Balance_€], 
    NPL_Amount_Last_Quarter AS NPL_Amount_Last_Q, 
    [NPL_Amount_€], On_Balance_Amount_Last_Quarter, 
    Material_Bucket, Material_Bucket_Last_Quarter
FROM
    dbo.Transfer_Final_Accounts_COM_WORK
GROUP BY 
    CRS, Date_Last_Updated, Loan_Code, [On_Balance_Amount_€], 
    [Off_Balance_Amount_€], [Total_Balance_€], NPL_Amount_Last_Quarter, 
    [NPL_Amount_€], On_Balance_Amount_Last_Quarter, Material_Bucket, 
    Material_Bucket_Last_Quarter
```

Query 3 connects the 2 above and results in 0 rows:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.Total_Balance,  
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.On_Balance_Last_Q, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.Off_Balance_Last_Q,    
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.NPL_Amount_Last_Quarter, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Year_of_Transfer, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Month_of_Transfer, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Day_of_Transfer, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.CRS AS Expr1, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Loan_Code AS Expr2, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Min_Date_Last_Updated, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.[On_Balance_Amount_€], 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.[Off_Balance_Amount_€], 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.[Total_Balance_€], 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.[NPL_Amount_€], 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.NPL_Amount_Last_Q, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.On_Balance_Amount_Last_Quarter, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.Material_Bucket, 
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.Material_Bucket_Last_Quarter
FROM 
    dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances ON dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Loan_Code = dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.Loan_Code 
                    AND dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates.Min_Date_Last_Updated = dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances.Date_Last_Updated
```

What is wrong with the connections why am I not taking the results from the above?

Comment: How does the third query "connect" the first two?  All three of these look *vastly different* from one another.

Comment: In which way are your too queries 'connected'? Both queries return a grouped result, whereas query 3 doesn't have a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: btw you could use alias names for the tables. It would be much more readable: `...  FROM dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates AS min_dates ...`

Answer (score 0):

When your query 3 doesn't return a row but the underlaying tables `dbo.Transfer_to_workout_min_dates` and `dbo.Transfer_to_Workout_Total_Balances` contain data, then most likely the join condition (`ON`) is not met for any entries in those tables.

Try to remove one of the terms (I would start with the `Min_Date_Last_Updated` one). It should change something. Then check in the result the both fields. You'll see that they differ and so are never equal.

Comment: Do you have any new information regarding the issue? Did my answer help?